# Decimal Clock for Strftime

Tags: clock

Is it possible to show decimal time, as in [Wiki - Decimal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time), on strftime?

If not, is there any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Actually **base 60** time is well suited to real-world usage. It can be easily divided by **12**, 10, **6**, 5, **4**, **3**, and **2**.

Whereas a day of **24** hours is 2/5 of 60, and can be divided by **12**, **6**, **4**, **3**, and **2**. This gives day/night, morning/afternoon, 3 eight-hour shifts (*the watch* periods) - all of which are now etched into our daily lives.

It dates back to at least the **Sumer** civilisation 3500-1900 BCE (~5000 years ago), if not even earlier (Samarra ~5000 BCE, Halaf ~6000 BCE, Jarmo ~7000 BCE).

Years, lunar months, tides, and seasons are messy. Pretending that **base 10** can hide all that detail is not necessarily an improvement.

---

***That said ..***

If you want this as a feature, you need to look at the underlying code libraries and functions to support this. If they exist, there is probably a way.

Comment: :) It is a lot easier to do math with decimal time.
I'm not a coder, just a normal user. I guess I'll have to propose as an add-on or something. Thank you for your answer!